# Control service in GUI

Tags: android

I am writing an app that uses a media player. I want to start the media player using the service so that the music can be played even if the application is closed (onDestroy is run). Should I use BindService (for control the service) and not unBinding that?

the life cycle of the Service would be a bit tricky, start at playing screen created and stopped when either the music is complete in background or music is stopped when the app is finished (onDestroy)

how should i implement my service to best fit the above case i need?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use BindService (for control the service) and not unBinding that?

No. You should call `startService()` to start it and `stopService()` to stop it (e.g., when the user presses the Stop button).

Comment: the thing is, if i use startService() and stopService() to control the life cycle of the service, are there any way to control the service on my GUI? say, ask the service to play music and stop music?

and once if the app crashes, i lose the connection with my service and i cannot control it somehow, the service seems not functioning after that...

Comment: @Eason Kazuya Yim: "are there any way to control the service on my GUI? say, ask the service to play music and stop music?" -- call `startService()` again, with `Intent` extras to control the operation.

Comment: that means i should keep the mediaPlayer unkilled and stick to the service?

Comment: @Eason Kazuya Yim: I have no idea what that means. A music player app that wants to have the music play even when the user leaves the activity would implement a `Service` that uses `MediaPlayer` to play back the music. The activity can use `startService()` both to initially start playback and to configure that playback later (e.g., choose the playlist). The activity can use `stopService()` to stop playback.